# Excel VBA - Transfer Data range from one sheet to another based on conditional text string

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, data-transfer

I am new to macros and am trying to transfer a data range from one worksheet to another based on a conditional text string.

Data in "inquires" sheet (Range "A5:G1200") needs to transfer to "quotes" sheet based on if column Range "K6:K1200" in "inquiries" sheet is a text string "Y" or "N". If text is "Y" we want the data rows with "y" to transfer, if the text is "N" we do not want rows with "N" to transfer.

Once the data range with "Y" transfers over to "quotes" sheet, we then need to transfer data from "Quotes" sheet (Range "A5:G1200" & and separate Range "L5:M1200") to "orders" sheet based on if column range "N6:N1200" in "quotes" sheet is a text string "Rec'vd" or "Closed". Same as above, If text is "Rec'vd" we want the data rows with "rec'vd" to transfer. If "Closed" then no data from "closed" rows should transfer.

Once all data is transferred to all 3 sheets based on text conditions. I want to have a 4th sheet that will filter this data based on a date range. I want to be able to type in a date range and then all data from each sheet ("inquires", "quotes", & "orders") to filter to that "master" 4th sheet. Each data sheet should have its own area (one below the other) on the master sheet to filter to.

Here is what I have so far..

```
Sub TransferTest1()
    Dim INQUIRE As Worksheet
    Dim QUOTE As Worksheet
    Dim ORDER As Worksheet
    Dim YString As String
    Dim RecString As String

    Set INQUIRE = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Inquiries")
    Set QUOTE = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Quotes")
    Set ORDER = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Orders")

    If INQUIRE.Range("K6:K1200") = "Y" Then
        INQUIRE.Range("A5:G1200").Copy QUOTE.Range("A5")
    End If

    If QUOTE.Range("N6:N1200") = "Rec'vd" Then
        QUOTE.Range("A5:G1200").Copy ORDER.Range("A5")
        QUOTE.Range("L5:M1200").Copy ORDER.Range("K5")
    End If
End Sub
```

I appreciate any and all help!

Robert Smithey

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical use-case for `Autofilter`.

```
With INQUIRE.Range("A4:K1200")
    .AutoFilter 11, "Y"
    .offset(1).Resize(, 7).Copy QUOTE.Range("A5")  ' columns A:G
    .AutoFilter
End With

With QUOTE.Range("A4:N1200")
    .AutoFilter 14, "Rec'vd"
    .offset(1).Resize(, 7).Copy ORDER.Range("A5") ' columns A:G
    .offset(1).Resize(, 2).offset(11).Copy ORDER.Range("K5")  ' columns L:M
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

Comment: A.S.H. thank you very much for the response. I ran the code you wrote and getting Run-time error '1004': "AutoFilter method of Range class failed". I have tried to do a little research and it seems that all variables are defined. Could you shed some light?

Comment: @R.Smithey This syndrome is usually because a previous autofilter was in place and you should clean it up. Try adding just `.AutoFilter` at the beginning of each `With` bloc. Also check that you do have some data in column `N` of the `QUOTE` worksheet.

Comment: A.S.H. I removed the filter drop down boxes on each excel sheet. I have tried a few different variations without any luck. I will continue to fiddle with it. The VBA module is blank other than the variable definitions/conditions and the with bloc statements are present in the code. There is data in all columns that are referenced in the with blocs.